# Managing devices connected to livepatch

Tags: ubuntu-one, canonical-livepatch

The question is about the newly introduced service of “livepatch”.

In short: Due to there is a limit of 3 machines per Ubuntu One account, is there a way for a user to manage his connected machines and possibly delete old/unused entries or if someone passes the threshold of three log-ins the forth has to be payed regardless of who many machines are in fact used?

In detail: Recently I made a clean install of 18.04 LTS. I was prompted to sign-in to livepatch with my Ubuntu One account and so I did.
A few days passed and for some reason, that its is irrelevant right now, I deleted the whole drive and reinstalled 18.04, signing-in to livepatch again when prompted.

Because I some times have to test things and I don’t want this to take place on my production system I used VirtualBox to set-up a second virtual 18.04 for testing purposes. Again I signed-in with my Ubuntu One account.

Yesterday I was looking for something in the snap repository and I noticed that livepatch has a proprietary license. Because it struck me as odd I went on searching about that and learned about the limit of three machines per user/account, hence the question above.

The way I see it, if the service doesn’t somehow check which machines are indeed active I will not be able to connect any other machine ever again for free, correct?